# Nested donut chart for comparison

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I am trying to make two donut plots to compare some metrics. The data frame is as below,

```
new_sum    var                 `1`   `2`
    <dbl> <chr>               <dbl> <dbl>
1    98.7 cnt_alerts           45.1  NA  
2    98.7 cnt_incidents_total  15.6  NA  
3    98.7 sum_of_events       100    NA  
4   100   cnt_alerts           NA    44.4
5   100   cnt_incidents_total  NA    16.2
6   100   sum_of_events        NA   100
```

So the two plots should represent the `1` and `2` columns, but the row `sum_of_events` should be taken from `new_sum` column. So in the end the two plots will look as follows (Trying to replicate with paint)

[image]

**DATA**

```
structure(list(new_sum = c(98.7093505166464, 98.7093505166464, 
98.7093505166464, 100, 100, 100), var = c("cnt_alerts", "cnt_incidents_total", 
"sum_of_events", "cnt_alerts", "cnt_incidents_total", "sum_of_events"
), `1` = c(45.0519047096481, 15.6423424701131, 100, NA, NA, NA
), `2` = c(NA, NA, NA, 44.4483592005942, 16.201786624667, 100
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Maybe try [circlize](https://jokergoo.github.io/circlize_book/book/high-level-plots.html), based on base graphics, not ggplot2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(
    id = rep(1:2, each = 3),
    value = coalesce(`1`, `2`),
    value = ifelse(var == "sum_of_events", new_sum, value)
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(var)) + 
  geom_col(aes(y = 100), position = 'identity', fill = 'white', col = 1, width = 0.5) +
  geom_col(aes(y = value), position = 'identity', fill = 'grey60', col = 1, width = 0.5) +
  facet_grid(~id) +
  coord_polar(theta = 'y') +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]